# Qual é a função do pyqtSignal?

Tags: python, pyqt

Fiz uma pesquisa sobre a classe `pyqtSignal` e seus métodos, porém não consegui compreender bem.

Alguém que trabalhe com essa classe, pode me explicar a sua função?